# Randomly Sample a Fixed Length Substring from a Larger String (R)

Tags: r, string, random

I have a long string of about 1000 characters (call it SuperString), and I want to randomly sample 100 substrings from SuperString.

Each substring should be 10 characters long, and the characters within substring should be in the same order as they were in SuperString.

**Example:**

```
SuperString = "ADKFKDSLFSDHKENNCNEUNCIEOCIKEMNKSDFU...KJSDLJDFSKLDJSLJ"
substrings = ["FSDHKENNCN", "ADKFKDSLFS", ... ,"OCIKEMNKS"]
```

Comment: Maybe use `sample()` to set starting point of calls to `substr()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# Create a SuperString
set.seed(87)
SuperString = paste(sample(LETTERS, 1000, replace=TRUE), collapse="")

# Function to sample 10 characters in a row, starting at a random point
# in the string
sampleString = function(string) {
    nStart = sample(1:991,1)
    substr(string, nStart, nStart + 9)
}

# Run the function 100 times
substrings = replicate(100, sampleString(SuperString))

substrings
[1] "VEOUELBFTD" "OPTCIDDNXK" "SFHNKKGOWR" "RVJQYYUSAZ" "MQMBMKCTTI" "ZKLWETGMVR"
[7] "OOXFLGCGPX" "DXAVUMQMBM" "HOORFCFABC" "AMOYPOXXRA" "TGKWKKZUEK" "UYPRPYQCMU" 
...
[91] "RZNSLOBFBK" "FKUKMDUQIK" "YGXDXAVUMQ" "SIRAMRBXSH" "TAILZPHZYS" "OEOUTGKWKK"
[97] "XFLGCGPXKZ" "EDRVJQYYUS" "RHUZLBFNQX" "MUWUODCCFT"
```